# Got empty response for: proxy.exporter.k8s.io/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes

when I run any command with kubectl, I get the following warning or error.

```
E0410 13:38:28.875682    7910 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for proxy.exporter.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: proxy.exporter.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I couldn't quite understand why. The resources that work with the image below are listed.

[image]